# Crash at the move vo,ao instruction

Tags: crash, mips

I got a weird system crash. The crash happens at the move instruction in `MIPS processor`. There is no memory access over this instruction - a register to register movement. I assume that the crash happens at the move instruction since the `epc` holds the address of the very next instruction.

```
jr ra;  
move v0,a0;  
lw a0,16(a0);
```

What can cause this?

And `ePC` holding third instruction even after `jr` instruction, is this due to pipelining.

Comment: MIPS doesn't do OO, does it? Because you'll notice that you are trying to load the register you just moved. Maybe it optimized this to load v0 directly before move?

Comment: Hi John. By OO, do you mean kernel OOPS?

Comment: By OO, I mean out-of-order execution where the processor rearranges the order statements execute in. Usually part of that strategy is to sorta split a lw into two instructions. As soon as you know the address to fetch and that it's value won't be changed, start the load. Do some other stuff (e.g. move v0,a0), then wait for the result to finally arrive from main memory. It is more of a CISC than a RISC thing to do, but I thought some RISC chips might do it.

Comment: @John Watts: Some MIPS CPUs, like the 74K are out of order (see http://www.mips.com/products/processor-cores/classic/mips32-74k). But an out-of-order CPU processes exceptions in-order, so that what you are suggesting cannot happen.

Comment: @markgz Thanks for the correct info. I just figured I'd take a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Given that EPC holds the address of the third instruction after the JR, then the crash is happening at that instruction.  The MOVE instruction is in the [branch delay slot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_delay_slot) of the JR, so it is executed before the JR. The JR returns to the LW instruction, which is where EPC is telling you that the crash is happening.

Incidentally, the MOVE instruction cannot cause any exceptions in the MIPS architecture (except for page faults on the instruction fetch).